# Pass a column field row wise as a table name inside the subquery

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

```sql
select B.name, B.id, count(select * from B.name) 
from B 
group by name;
```

How to access the parent query column value inside the sub query as a table name? The table name will be different for all the rows in the table B.

Looking for the syntax if its possible, or any workarounds for this scenario

Comment: using B.name as table name for the sub query , which is not the correct syntax. So whats the correct alternative

Comment: You would have to use dynamic SQL; honestly the design you have is likely the real problem you need to solve here.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `B.name` is the name of a table you want the count of rows from, you could try the following that gets the rowcount from the *sys.partitions* DMV

```
select b.[name], b.Id, p.rows
from b
join sys.tables t on t.[name] = b.[name] 
                 and t.schema_id = Schema_Id('dbo') /* or column with the schema name */
join sys.partitions p on p.object_id = t.object_id 
                     and p.index_id <= 1;
```